# How to use an array of strings in a solidity mapping?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I need to store a mapping between a string to items which are 128 bytes long in a `solidity` contract. The problem is that the longest bytes data type is `bytes32`, which is not long enough, and if I try to store my strings in a `string array` I get the following error:

```
This type is only supported in the experimental ABI encoder. Use "pragma experimental abiencoderv2;" to enable this feature
```

So I cannot use `bytes32` because it's not big enough. I cannot use `bytes` because it's not supported. And I cannot use `string[]` because it's experimental and not recommended in production.

Any solution?

This is the contract I'm using:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract SomeData {    
    struct Data {
        string id;
        string[3] items;
    }

    mapping (string => Data) dataItems;

    function addData(string id, string[3] items) public {
        Data memory data = Data(id, items);
        data.id = id;
        data.items = items;
        dataItems[id] = data;
    }

    function getDataItems(string id) public view returns (string[3]){
        return dataItems[id].items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the maximum length of each individual `string`, you can use a static 2 dimensional array:

```
contract SomeData {

    struct Data {
        string id;
        byte[128][100] items;
    }

    mapping (string => Data) dataItems;


    function addData(string id, byte[128][100] items) public {
        Data memory data = Data(id, items);
        data.id = id;
        data.items = items;
        dataItems[id] = data;
    }

    function getDataItems(string id) public view returns (byte[128][100]){
        return (dataItems[id].items);
    }
}
```

Note, only 2-dimensional dynamic arrays are not allowed. You could even use `byte[128][]` if you wanted to.

Comment: Thanks. It is static but it has 100 items (I had 3 in the example just so I can work on it in Remix). It would be kind of crazy to have a method signature with 100 items.

Comment: Updated answer based on your comment.

Comment: How would you call the addData method? Say with an array of `byte[128][3]`

Comment: In Remix? Well, that's a pain because you have to provide each byte including trailing 0x00 values. As an example, if your parameter was `byte[3][2]`, you would pass in `[["0x11","0x22", "0x33"], ["0x44","0x55", "0x66"]]`.